# Hardware specification terminology

Tags: analog, adc, resistance, voltage-measurement

I have a hardware [specification document of a product attached below.](https://www.ifm.com/restservices/in/en/assets/c3VwcGxpZXJzL2lmbS9kb2N1bWVudHMvUERGL0NSMDQwMy5QREY=)

I am able to understand the following parameters:

- Input voltage - This is defined for the range of input voltage
- Resolution - Means, I need to have 12 bits ADC on micro-controller
- Input frequency & accuracy - Self-explanatory

But I am not able to understand the purpose of "**FS Input Resistance**" parameter.

1. Is this full-scale input resistance? If so, what is the purpose of this parameter?
2. I want to read the feedback of this voltage on micro-controller which I am planning through a voltage divider. Do I need to take any additional precaution because of this parameter?

   [image]

Comment: What exactly is this spec for? "Hardware" could be anything. Simply link the datasheet instead of posting pictures of it.

Comment: @Lundin You can refer this product link: https://www.ifm.com/in/en/product/CR0403. Actually, I need to know the parameter meaning, which I thought might be Hardware independent.

Comment: Ok this doesn't make much sense with the datasheet either. In particular "input frequency" doesn't make sense. They seem to make certain assumptions about the nature of the data. Ask the manufacturer how to interpret this.

Comment: @Lundin on the contrary, the input frequency spec makes perfect sense, like essentially anything with an ADC the device has a limited signal bandwidth over which it is specified to work, and this one is the most common case where that bandwidth is from DC to some maximum frequency.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what "I want to read the feedback of this voltage on micro-controller" means.  As the spec you have is an *input* you don't really have anything you *can* read with something else.  You would probably have to consider instead the specification of whatever is *driving* the signal you want to measure.  At best, if you don't have that and you make the input impedance of your new circuit much higher than that of the existing instrument, maybe you can neglect it - but that probably means you need a buffer amplifier, not a voltage divider.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No it doesn't make any sense. ADCs have conversion time and sample speed. Now you are telling me it makes perfect sense that a bloody Power PC can't sample faster than 500Hz? Now as it happens, I know that most Freescale Power PC (MPC56 etc) have a maximum input frequency of 500 **kHz**, thousand times faster than what this datasheet claims. Thus, either the datasheet doesn't make any sense or they made something very smelly with the internal hardware of the computer.

Comment: @Lundin again you are confusing wildly different topics.  Instruments are designed to sample a useful frequency range.   This instrument has the stated analog limitation, which is perfectly reasonable for many uses presumably including those it was intended for.  It has absolutely no bearing on what some other instrument built for different purposes could do.  You are following a wild tangent with no relevance whatsoever to the asker's question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a problem with your pdf reader. The one I am currently using (Adobe Reader) places the FS with the +/-1% accuracy.[image: Example]

Comment: This seems to be the definitive answer.